# Restler3 RC4: oAuth doesn't work

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, restler

Just updated my restler 3 to release candidate 4 to try oAuth2 implementation. I've a restler 3 server and client, the server should offer an oAuth2.0 server and the client should implement oAuth2.0. But the oAuth2.0 client example index.php page stays empty. 
What did I wrong? I set all permissions recursively to 777 and installed any dependencies from composer (I'm new to composer). But the stuff got downloaded to restler's vendor folder so it's there.

Thank's for reading and answering.
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.htaccess` file turns off the display_errors. That's why you are getting a blank response.

Change it as shown below

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag display_errors On
</IfModule>
```

Then you will get the clue!

Comment: Oh maaan, how could I ignore that? Now I get »
Fatal error: Class 'Twig_Loader_Filesystem' not found in …/Restler-master/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Format/HtmlFormat.php on line 175« I'm trying around now.

Comment: Soooo. Here we go: the problem was that I commented   line 2-8 and 15 out (vendor/restler.php) because it causes empty api-list and routing fails (every route failed). So I uncommented the lines and demo is app working now.