# Restler3 RC4: api-list stays empty

Tags: php, autoload, restler

I've got a problem with new Restler3 RC4: My API list in resource.json is just empty:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "1",
    "swaggerVersion": "1.1",
    "basePath": "xxxxxx/API/index.php",
    "apis": 
    [

    ]
}
```

But by uncommenting the vendor/restler.php file to look like this:

```
require_once 'Luracast/Restler/AutoLoader.php';
return call_user_func(function () 
{
    $loader = Luracast\Restler\AutoLoader::instance();
    spl_autoload_register($loader);
    return $loader;
});
```

It will work. But that way the twig-template stuff and so on doesn't work (Have a look here: [Restler3 RC4: oAuth doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895576/restler3-rc4-oauth-doesnt-work)).
So where is the problem right now? 
Of course, it's about autoloading, right? I hate auto loading! -.-

Thanks guys,
Jan

**UPDATE** 1
According to https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/issues/207#issuecomment-25678729 I updated to the latest stable release and now my resource.json prints the following (the first 'Strict Standards' appears 193 times):

```
<b>Strict Standards</b>:  Only variables should be passed by reference in <b>xxxx/API/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Routes.php</b> on line <b>228</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at xxxx/API/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Routes.php:228) in <b>xxxx/API/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Filter/RateLimit.php</b> on line <b>119</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at xxxx/API/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Routes.php:228) in <b>xxxx/API/restler/vendor/Luracast/Restler/Filter/RateLimit.php</b> on line <b>137</b><br />
{
    "apiVersion": "1",
    "swaggerVersion": "1.1",
    "basePath": "xxx/API/index.php",
    "apis": [
        {
            "path": "/resources/consumer.{format}",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "path": "/resources/request.{format}",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "path": "/resources/shorturl.{format}",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "path": "/resources/comment.{format}",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "path": "/resources/favorites.{format}",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "path": "/resources/options.{format}",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "path": "/resources/plugins.{format}",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "path": "/resources/themes.{format}",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "path": "/resources/updater.{format}",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "path": "/resources/preferences.{format}",
            "description": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, I get my apis! :) But how can I fix the warnings?

Comment: Can you give any additional information? Maybe your index.php file for instance? Also it might be good if you could just reduce the `addAPIClass()` calls to just one and then include that source file too. On a side note, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Would also like to see whatever class you are referencing with the `addAuthenticationClass()` call too.

Comment: Just some additional information (problem already solved): I'm running php 5.4.19 and I didn't use addAuthenticationClass().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have just just released an update to fix this strict standards warning

That should fix it for you